# RSpec: hash_including not working as I expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Consider the following json response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "someFunction": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Email was already confirmed, please try signing in",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 9,
          "column": 2
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "someFunction"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "USER_ERROR"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now in a test I'm expecting the following to be a valid response:

```
expect(json_response[:errors]).to contain_exactly(
  hash_including(
    message: "Email was already confirmed, please try signing in.",
    extensions: { code: 'USER_ERROR' }
  )
)
```

The above response should be valid except that my tests are saying that it's not:

```
expected collection contained:  [hash_including(:message=>"Email was already confirmed, please try signing in.", :extensions=>{:code=>"USER_ERROR"})]
actual collection contained:    [{:extensions=>{:code=>"USER_ERROR"}, :locations=>[{:column=>9, :line=>2}], :message=>"Email was already confirmed, please try signing in", :path=>["someFunction"]}]
the missing elements were:      [hash_including(:message=>"Email was already confirmed, please try signing in.", :extensions=>{:code=>"USER_ERROR"})]
the extra elements were:        [{:extensions=>{:code=>"USER_ERROR"}, :locations=>[{:column=>9, :line=>2}], :message=>"Email was already confirmed, please try signing in", :path=>["someFunction"]}]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are doing so much in a test (and you don't have to nest matchers)

Because contain_exactly matcher will return true or error.

So a suggestion try not to do complex test and try to avoid more than [one expectations](http://www.betterspecs.org/#single) on the same test

```
  it 'includes data and errors' do
    expect(json_response.keys).to contain_exactly(:data, :errors)
  end

  it 'Email error has message' do
    expect(json_response[:errors][0][:message]).to eq 'Email was already confirmed, please try signing in'
  end

  it 'Email error has code' do
    expect(json_response[:errors][0][:extensions]).to eql(code: 'USER_ERROR')
  end
```

It should work

Comment: This is a fine workaround but doesn't really answer why the original code didn't work

Comment: @maxpleaner you're right. However, I did figured it out. I'm expecting a period at the end but I'm not getting that back as the result (I'm pulling from Devise's locale file and the messages do not contain periods which I was expecting). I guess it would've been easier to catch my error is RSpec was able to narrow in on the actual issue.

Comment: @Horacio btw, I was able to figure out my mistake using the `:message` test in your answer, so I'll give you a +1. This is a mistake I wont make next time though because I'll know that the error Rspec returns doesn't necessarily mean my mistake is as complicated as I thought.

Comment: @aarona ah shit, i missed that too. But, on the plus side, I always fine it  nice to realize that the framework actually does work ... I would much rather have a typo than to fight the framework

Comment: Yeah, I may even post an enhancement suggestion to RSpec and see if they'd consider reworking the error output. See my answer, I think it might be caused by combining `contain_exactly` and `hash_including`. The error output makes it seem almost like `hash_including` shouldn't be used here.

Comment: The error on the original code its that you have 2 matchers nested, ```hash_including``` its inside of ```contain_exactly```has includint wont return the element it will return TRUE or ERROR because it's a matcher.

Answer (score 0):

Using one of Horacio's tests, I was able to determine I was expecting a period. Dismissing a core function of Rspec and not using it is not the solution that I wanted. However, this was a learning experience for myself and hopefully anyone else who comes across this question wondering what they did wrong, they'll see a simple mistake from pairing `contain_exactly` and `hash_including` together may cause your error output to deceive you into thinking you're doing something really wrong when in actuality, you probably made a simple mistake.

This sanity check:

```
expect(json_response[:errors][0][:message]).to eq 'Email was already confirmed, please try signing in'
```

Resulted in me finding my simple mistake:

```
 expected: "Email was already confirmed, please try signing in."
      got: "Email was already confirmed, please try signing in"
```